# Oracle union giving error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, union

I am trying to create a view in Oracle to show all rooms available in the hotel that are not booked out.

If they are booked out there will be a record in RoomBasket. So I am trying to select all rooms not in RoomBasket between the checkin and checkout dates (RoomBasket.datein, RoomBasket.dateout)

But the query kept returning 0 results when I used inner joins and outer (left/right) joins, I think it's because it is not joined on to a table of dates so it will have 0 results. So now I am trying to do a Union to the Room table which has a record of all rooms, as I think that would select all Rooms and then negate the ones which are booked out?

I can't get my syntax correct and I played around with loads of forms of this query:

```
CREATE VIEW availability AS
    (SELECT * FROM RoomBasket rb
        WHERE TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd') 
        NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE(rb.datein, 'yyyymmdd') AND TO_DATE(rb.dateout, 'yyyymmdd')
        UNION (SELECT r.id room, rt.type type, rt.price price FROM Room r, RoomType rt)
    );
```

But if it works I get 0 results and if it doesn't work I get syntax errors. At the moment the error is:

> query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` in the first query, actually list the columns you need. A `UNION` requires the same # of columns in all queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no predicate on your join of `Room` to `RoomType`, so you get a cross join.  That is unlikely to be what you want.

Furthermore, your `union` looks like it's trying to add unrelated data to the room data.  Your description of the problem suggests that you want to use the `RoomBasket` data to *filter* the other data instead -- that requires a join or a subquery.

Something more along these lines would do what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW availability AS (
  SELECT r.id room, rt.type type, rt.price price
  FROM
    Room r
    INNER JOIN RoomType rt
      ON rt.id = r.type
    LEFT JOIN RoomBasket rb
      ON rb.room = r.id
        AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN TO_DATE(rb.datein, 'yyyymmdd')
          AND TO_DATE(rb.dateout, 'yyyymmdd')
  WHERE rb.room IS NULL
);
```

The `WHERE` predicate has the effect of selecting those rows of the left table (`Room JOIN RoomType`) which are not matched by any row of the right table (`RoomBasket`).

Answer (score 3):

Your first query is returning a different number of columns than your second query, thus they cannot be unioned.  Specify the columns for the first query explicitly instead of using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working correctly like this:

```
CREATE VIEW availability AS
            (SELECT 
                r.id room, 
                rt.type type, 
                rt.price price 
                FROM Room r 
                INNER JOIN RoomType rt ON r.type = rt.id
                INNER JOIN RoomBasket rb ON r.id = rb.room
                WHERE TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
                    NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE(rb.datein, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
                            AND TO_DATE(rb.dateout, 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
            )
    ;
```

Comment: It looks like that stands to return duplicates of rooms that have multiple corresponding `RoomBasket` rows outside the date range you're using.  There's enough information for me to update my answer with correct column names, though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah that one gave the incorrect result, but I got it working already like this. Edited the answer.

Comment: No, that's worse.  Not only can it still produce dupes, it also will *miss* rooms that have no corresponding `RoomBasket` row at all.  Perhaps your `RoomBasket` data are such that it happens to produce the result you expect, but the form of the query does not ensure that it will continue to do so.

Comment: `SYSDATE` is a date; you don't need to call `TO_DATE` on it.  When you do, it is implicitly converted to a string, then explicitly converted back to a date.  At best this is just unnecessary work; but it can cause wrong results if the implicit conversion format is not the same as the explicit one.